# Delete Columns with same elements

Tags: python, arrays, sorting

```
arr_2d = np.array([[ 1,  2,  4,  9, 3, 10],
                   [ 1,  3,  4, 12, 3, 15],
                   [ 1,  6,  4, 16, 3, 22],
                   [ 1, 10,  4, 21, 3, 30]])
arr_2d_copy = arr_2d.copy()
for col_idx in range(arr_2d.shape[1]):
    are_all_same = np.all(arr_2d[:,col_idx] == arr_2d[:,col_idx][0])
    print('Same? ', are_all_same)
    if are_all_same:
        arr_2d_copy = np.delete(arr_2d_copy, col_idx, axis=1)
        
print(arr_2d_copy)
```

I am trying to get an output like this -

```
array([[ 2,  9, 10],
       [ 3, 12, 15],
       [ 6, 16, 22],
       [10, 21, 30]])
```

My code clearly isn't working because of indexing error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are deleting entries in the same time you going througt your array so you reducing your array size.

To avoid this create a list where you will store your index to delete and after your loop you delete it.

```
arr_2d = np.array([[ 1,  2,  4,  9, 3, 10],
                   [ 1,  3,  4, 12, 3, 15],
                   [ 1,  6,  4, 16, 3, 22],
                   [ 1, 10,  4, 21, 3, 30]])
arr_2d_copy = arr_2d.copy()
indices_to_delete = []
for col_idx in range(arr_2d.shape[1]):
    are_all_same = np.all(arr_2d[:,col_idx] == arr_2d[:,col_idx][0])
    print('Same? ', are_all_same)
    if are_all_same:
        indices_to_delete.append(col_idx)

arr_2d_copy = np.delete(arr_2d_copy, indices_to_delete, axis=1)
        
print(arr_2d_copy)
```

Answer (score 2):

Either by uniqe each column to check if it only has one element, or broadcast the first row to compare the array.

Way1: `np.apply_along_axis(lambda column:len(np.unique(column))>1, axis=0, arr=arr_2d)`

Way2: `(arr_2d != arr_2d[0]).any(axis=0)`

---

Here is the result

```
import numpy as np

arr_2d = np.array([[1, 2, 4, 9, 3, 10],
                   [1, 3, 4, 12, 3, 15],
                   [1, 6, 4, 16, 3, 22],
                   [1, 10, 4, 21, 3, 30]])

filtered_cols = arr_2d[:, np.apply_along_axis(lambda column:len(np.unique(column))>1, axis=0, arr=arr_2d)]

#filtered_cols = arr_2d[:, (arr_2d != arr_2d[0]).any(axis=0)]
print(filtered_cols)


[[ 2  9 10]
 [ 3 12 15]
 [ 6 16 22]
 [10 21 30]]
```

Answer (score 1):

When deleting columns from a numpy array within a loop, **the shape of the array changes**, which can lead to **indexing errors**. Hence I used a method to make sure our index values line up correctly even after changes in the array shape.

```
import numpy as np
arr_2d = np.array([[ 1,  2,  4,  9, 3, 10],
               [ 1,  3,  4, 12, 3, 15],
               [ 1,  6,  4, 16, 3, 22],
               [ 1, 10,  4, 21, 3, 30]])
arr_2d_copy = arr_2d.copy()
for col_idx in range(arr_2d.shape[1]):
    are_all_same = np.all(arr_2d[:,col_idx] == arr_2d[:,col_idx][0])
    print('Same? ', are_all_same)
    if are_all_same:
       ref_index = col_idx -(arr_2d.shape[1]- arr_2d_copy.shape[1])  # adjust index 
       arr_2d_copy = np.delete(arr_2d_copy, ref_index, axis=1)
print(arr_2d_copy)
```